# Would Jericho be considered science fiction?

Tags: discussion, scope

I mean, there is nothing scientifically impossible or not yet possible in [the series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jericho_%28TV_series%29).

On the other hand, it definitely is *fiction* and it has a small amount of *science*.

Comment: Where does the criteria "scientifically impossible or not yet possible" come from?

Comment: @Bill: Ok, I admit I can't back it with a reference, but science fiction usually meets that criterion.

Answer (score 9):

Its hard as Nellius said, but if we consider the Road and Mad Max in sci-fi genre, Jericho will be there by definition.

Sociological aspects of post nuclear trauma were main plot of the series but i love the background plot working around a conspiracy in US Gov. and its definitely a future projection or and alternate history story.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say it's not science fiction. The "not really possible" element in the series is basically the fact that a nuclear apocalypse happened, which I don't think really counts as science fiction.

There are many science-fiction titles which deal with a post-apocalyptic setting, but given that Jericho was set in the present day, I'd struggle to classify it as sci-fi.